# How is electric flux density independent of medium?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

I understand that the scalar quantity, electric flux, $\phi$, is dependent on the medium.
Also, mathematically, I understand how vector quantity electric flux density, $\mathbf{D}$, is independent of the medium when represented as
$$
\mathbf{D}=\epsilon\mathbf{E}  ............Eq(1)
$$
where $\epsilon$ is the relative permittivity.
But electric flux density, which is defined as "the eclectic flux per unit area" can also be given as
$$
\mathbf{D}=\frac{\phi}{\mathbf{A}}............Eq(2)
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is the area.
ie how to show
$$
\frac{\phi}{\mathbf{A}} = \epsilon\mathbf{E}
$$
I)How can dividing the electric flux, $\phi$, by area, $\mathbf{A}$, remove the dependency on the medium?

II)Also, how can the scalar quantity $\phi$ become equal to a vector quantity $\epsilon\mathbf{E}$ just by dividing with the area?

Comment: The vector $\mathbf D$ is called the electric displacement (field).is defined as $\displaystyle \mathbf {D} \equiv \varepsilon _{0}\mathbf {E} +\mathbf {P}$, where $\displaystyle \varepsilon _{0}$ is the permittivity of free space, and $\mathbf P$ is the (macroscopic) density of the permanent and induced electric dipole moments in the material, called the polarization density.

Comment: @Farcher So the $\epsilon_0{\mathbf{E}}$ part is not dependent on the medium. The dependency on medium comes only due to polarization ${\mathbf{P}}$ ?

Comment: @Farcher Can you please shed any light on this since $/epsilon_0$? Would meanl still be dependent on the 'medium' ie vaccum

Comment: Your statement *The dependency on medium comes only due to polarization * is correct.

Comment: That would mean D is dependent on the medium which is not right?!

Comment: [Electric displacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field) depends on free charges.

Comment: I can see that displacement field $D = \epsilon_o \epsilon_r E$ wouldn't that make it independent of the medium (since the equation for E of a charge has $\epsilon_o \epsilon_r$ in the denominator)?

Answer (score 1):

Flux (dΦ) is defined with the dot product of the two vectors; (E) and (dA).  You can say that E = Φ/A only if (E) is uniform and perpendicular to A. You are working with scaler magnitudes.

Comment: Thank you. This answers my second question. Bu the fist question still remains. How is it all connected to flux density as your answer is in terms of electric flux only.

Comment: Also isn't the equation supposed to be $$
\frac{\phi}{\mathbf{A}} = \epsilon\mathbf{E}
$$  and not just $$
\frac{\phi}{\mathbf{A}} =\mathbf{E}
$$